# Signal saturating after transistor amplifier

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, common-emitter

I'm trying to amplify this noise coming from Q1 but it looks like it's saturating at the collector of Q2 (as you can see in the image). How can I resize the resistor values such that the signal does not saturate?

I have 11.8V at the collector.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fry0Ne.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have omitted some things in your original schematic.
Here is your schematic with my notes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2facKzW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- I fail to see the reason for a voltage divider. You only have 24V but you want 12V?
- You didn't connect the C2 and C3 with R2 and R3 to complete the voltage divider.
- Is bottom, negative side of the 24V supply supposed to be ground or is it the lower end of R6?
- R5 was 4.7Ω, but I'm sure that was a typo, should be 4.7kΩ.

Here is a better, working schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG40i9.png)</sup>

The values for this circuit are from https://www.eeweb.com/simple-white-noise-generator/  
Their schematic is the same:
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice the disconnection at the voltage divider and the capacitors. I corrected that. The reason for the voltage divider is to power an op-amp further in the circuit - but I disconnected it to concentrate on this section of the circuit, because that's where it's saturating. And in fact, it is 4.7kR at R5. I'm sorry for my mistakes (I've corrected them)

Comment: In comparison to that circuit, R3 is 5x greater than R2. Should my resistors ratio be the same in order to not saturate? Because the problem I'm having (and I don't get why) is the saturation over the positive values. What in the common emitter amplifier controls the upper saturation point? Or does it have to do with the transistor I'm using to amplify? I'm still learning circuits, so I apologize if my questions are silly. I've been searching for a while but couldn't yet grasp the amplification/saturation of transistors

Comment: R2 with C2 is for temperature stability. R3 produces a voltage drop from the collector current to give you the output signal voltage. In your original circuit, the Q2 emitter resistor was too high, which produced a high voltage drop, while Q1 emitter resistor at the same time was too low, which gave too much current to Q2 and brought it into saturation. That is fixed here.

Comment: even with the resistor values of that circuit, it saturates :/

Comment: Have you actually MADE the circuit or are you just doing a simulation?